# How to instantiate a mapped class? (swift - alamofireObjectMapper)

Tags: swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I have this mapped class caled Movie and I make an API request that returns me this type. How can I instantiate this class with the values of my API response?

Movie mapped class:

```
class Movie: Mappable {

var posterURL  : String?
var title      : String?
var runtime    : String?
var director   : String?
var actors     : String?
var genre      : String?
var plot       : String?
var production : String?
var released   : String?
var year       : String?
var imdbID     : String?
var imdbRating : String?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    posterURL  <- map["Poster"]
    title      <- map["Title"]
    runtime    <- map["Runtime"]
    director   <- map["Director"]
    actors     <- map["Actors"]
    genre      <- map["Genre"]
    plot       <- map["Plot"]
    production <- map["Production"]
    released   <- map["Released"]
    year       <- map["Year"]
    imdbID     <- map["imdbID"]
    imdbRating <- map["imdbRating"]
  }
}
```

And in my MovieViewController I'm making the API call and passing the values for my outlet label. 
But I would like to instantiate this class by assigning the values ​​obtained in my API call.

```
func getMovieById() {

    let requestURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(String(describing: imdbID!))"
    print("URL: \(requestURL)")


    Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in
        print("|MovieController| Response is: \(response)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let spinnerActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
            spinnerActivity.label.text = "Loading";
            spinnerActivity.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
        }

        let movie = response.result.value


        if let posterURL = movie?.posterURL {
            print("Poster URL: \(posterURL)")

            let imgStg: String = posterURL
            print("---> Image string: \(imgStg)")
            let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg)
            let imgSrc = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL!, cacheKey: imgStg)

            self.movPosterImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.movPosterImageView.frame.size.width/2
            self.movPosterImageView.clipsToBounds = true

            //image cache with KingFisher
            self.movPosterImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgSrc)

        }


        if let title = movie?.title {
            print("Title: \(title)")
            self.movTitleLabel.text = title
        }


        if let runtime = movie?.runtime {
            print("Runtime: \(runtime)")
            self.movRuntimeLabel.text = runtime
        }

        if let genre = movie?.genre {
            print("Genre: \(genre)")
            self.movGenreLabel.text = genre
        }

        if let plot = movie?.plot {
            print("Plot: \(plot)")
            self.movPlotTextView.text = plot
        }

        if let rating = movie?.imdbRating {
            print("Rating: \(rating)")
            self.movRatingLabel.text = rating
        }

        if let director = movie?.director {
            print("Director: \(director)")
            self.movDirectorLabel.text = director
        }

        if let production = movie?.production {
            print("Production: \(production)")
            self.movProductionLabel.text = production
        }

        if let actors = movie?.actors {
            print("Actors: \(actors)")
            self.movActorsLabel.text = actors
        }

        if let released = movie?.released {
            print("Released in: \(released)")
            self.movReleasedLabel.text = released
        }





        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
        }

    }//Alamofire.request

}//getMovieByID()
```

It would be something like

```
let movieDetails: Movie = Movie(plot = movie?.plot, title = movie?.title, ...)
```

How can I do this with a mappable class?

---

### Update

I'm trying to organize this things and also I'll have to reuse code, so did this inside functions seems better for me. So, I started separating the API call putting like this:

file: OMDB.swift

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper



func getMovieIdFromAPI(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Movie) -> () ) {

    let requestURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID)"

    print("|getMovieIdFromAPI|   URL: \(requestURL)")


    Alamofire.request(requestURL).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<Movie>) in
        print("|Alamofire request|   Response is: \(response)")

        if let movieResult = response.result.value{
            completionHandler(movieResult)
        }
      }
  }
```

Next step, I'm trying to create a MovieDAO, and here I'll have to instantiate my object, right? So, in the same file as my Movie class is, I've created a MovieDAO class with this function:

```
class MovieDAO {

func getMovieDetailed<Movie: Mappable>(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Movie) -> ()) {

    getMovieIdFromAPI(imdbID: imdbID, completionHandler: {
        (movieResult) in

        let mapper = Mapper<Movie>()
        let movieDetailed = mapper.map(movieResult)!



        completionHandler(movieDetailed)

    })

  }

}
```

But I didn't understood very well the answer and the xcode gives me an error in

```
   let movieDetailed = mapper.map(movieResult)!
                              ^Error: Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads
```

Could you explain how can I use the answer given in this case?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectMapper is what helps you get an instance of the model class, with the property values set as per your API response. You will need to do the last step where in you tell ObjectMapper to do the 'mapping' procedure with the json you provide it.You can use this generic method to parse response for any Mappable class

```
static func parseModel<Model: Mappable>(modelResponse modelResponse: AnyObject, modelClass: Model.Type) ->  Model? {

    let mapper = Mapper<Model>()
    let modelObject = mapper.map(modelResponse)!

    return modelObject
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answered. My goal is to organize my functions separated. See if you can help me one more time, take a look at the update I did in my question.